# Multi-variable assignment, using lists?

Tags: python, variable-assignment

For a multi-assignment the left side should be tuple, so first is a normal tuple assignment.

But why doesn’t the list assignment generate an error, it is a list and not a tuple:

```
m = ['have', 'fun']
x, y = m
[a, b] = 1, 2
```

Comment: Because it *doesn't* have to be a tuple. See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements, it's actually referred to as a `target_list`: *"If the target is a target list enclosed in parentheses or in square brackets..."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both tuple and list syntax is supported. See the [`target` definition in the *Assignment statements* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements).

> ```
> target          ::=  identifier
>                      | "(" [target_list] ")"
>                      | "[" [target_list] "]"
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> Assignment of an object to a target list, optionally enclosed in parentheses or square brackets [...]

No actual tuple or list is created here, it is just *syntax* that echoes the syntax for lists and tuples. There is no difference between using either tuple or list syntax in an assignment target.